Can't use the codecept.conf.js plugin feature in .ts test file
I had this plugin added in codecept.conf.js and installed the relevant package using  npm install codeceptjs-xray-cloud-helper.
codecept.conf.js file
commentStep: {
      enabled: true,
      registerGlobal:'xray_'
    }

When the test file is in .js extension I could use the feature in the test
l.js file
Scenario('test something',  ({ I }) => {
  xray_`step1`;
  I.amOnPage('https://github.com');
  xray_`step2`;
  I.dontSee('GitHub');
  //xray_`step2`;
  console.log(process.env.PROJECT_KEY)
  console.log("End")
  console.log(process.env.Xray_ClientId)
})

But when the test file is in .ts extension I can't use the feature in the test. Visual studio return Cannot find name 'xray_'.
l.ts file
Scenario('test something',  ({ I }) => {
  xray_`step1`;
  I.amOnPage('https://github.com');
  xray_`step2`;
  I.dontSee('GitHub');
  //xray_`step2`;
  console.log(process.env.PROJECT_KEY)
  console.log("End")
  console.log(process.env.Xray_ClientId)
})

I like to use the CommentStep feature used in .ts tests file
xray_`step1`;

